# IS NULL with CASE WHEN statment in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, case

I have been through many similar questions but no desired result.

I have two tables:

Table `Listings`:

```
SKU(int)    EAN(int)

1           923983737483
2           998379847983
3           978979879080
```

Table `Stock`

```
SKU(int)            qtyInHand(int)

1                   4
2                   NULL
3                   2
```

I want to get the list of SKUs, EAN and qtyInHand  based on the following conditions

Example:

```
Select 
    Listings.SKU, Listings.EAN, 
    IF (Stock.qtyInHand is null or stock.qtyInHand < 2) then 0 AS Stock
```

I have used the following query but it still list null values under stock field.

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
      WHEN (dbo.Stock.qtyInHand IS NULL) OR (dbo.Stock.qtyInHand < 2) 
      THEN 0 
   END AS Stock, 
   dbo.Listings.SKU, dbo.Listings.EAN
FROM 
   dbo.Listings 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   dbo.Stock ON dbo.Listings.SKU = dbo.Stock.SKU
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, Isnull() Function

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN (Isnull(dbo.Stock.qtyInHand,0) < 2) 
        THEN 0 
        Else dbo.Stock.qtyInHand
        END AS Stock
        , dbo.Listings.SKU
        , dbo.Listings.ASIN 
    FROM dbo.Listings 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Stock ON dbo.Listings.SKU = dbo.Stock.SKU
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `CASE` statement does not include an `ELSE` to cover the situation where `qtyInHand` is not NULL or is greater than or equal to 2. As stated in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), the `CASE` statement evaluates to NULL whenever none of the `WHEN` expressions are true.

Comment: The query worked for me. It lists 0 where the qtyInHand is null OR less then 2 and also list all values greater then 2. Can you prove your statement practically.

Comment: @AK47's code does include the `ELSE`; however, your original query `SELECT CASE WHEN (dbo.Stock.qtyInHand IS NULL) OR (dbo.Stock.qtyInHand < 2) THEN 0 END AS Stock, dbo.Listings.SKU, dbo.Listings.EAN FROM dbo.Listings LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Stock ON dbo.Listings.SKU = dbo.Stock.SKU` does **not** (which is why you were getting NULLs).